# Expressing the basis of the irreps of S3 in terms of the basis of the tensor product of the regular representation with itself

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, representation-theory

$S^3$ has 3 irreps: $V_1,V_{-1}$, and $V_2$ with basis $<v_1+v_2+v_3>, <v_1-v_2+v_3>, <v_1-v_2, v_2-v_3>$ respectively. If I take $V_2 \otimes V_2$ then by character theory it's obvious that $V_2 \otimes V_2 \cong V_1 \oplus V_{-1} \oplus V_2$. I now want to be able to express the previous irreps basis in terms of the basis of $V_2 \otimes V_2$. i.e some linear combination of the form $a_1(v_1-v_2)\otimes (v_1-v_2)+a_2(v_1-v_2)\otimes (v_2-v_3)+a_3(v_2-v_3)\otimes (v_1-v_2)+a_4(v_2-v_3)\otimes (v_2-v_3)$.

For brevity, $e = v_1+v_2+v_3, f = v_1-v_2+v_3, h_1 = v_1-v_2, h_2 = v_2-v_3$. I suspect I start by writing $<e\otimes e>, <f\otimes f>, <h_1 \otimes h_1, h_2 \otimes h_2>$. By the way groups act on tensors these must be invariant. Then I get stuck. I think I have to distribute out the tensor products, and then somehow set up a linear system to find the coefficients?

In Fulton Harris there is an answer to a similar question, but the basis for $V_2$ are the cubic roots of unity (the solution is also much better than setting up some huge system).

I feel like im missing some obvious linear algebra here.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are getting a little confused somewhere. I am assuming $\{v_1,v_2,v_3\}$ is a basis for the permutation representation $\mathbb{C}^3$. Then you are correct in that $\langle v_1+v_2+v_3 \rangle$ and $\langle v_1 - v_2, v_2 - v_3 \rangle$ give a realisation of the trivial and standard representation of $S_3$ as subrepresentations of $\mathbb{C}^3$ respectively.

However, do not know where you got $\langle v_1 - v_2 + v_3\rangle$ from. There are quite a few reasons why this could not possibly be a basis/realisation of the alternating representation. One of which being that it's not even closed under the action of $S_3$ (think about action of $(1 2)$, for example). Another being that you have already "used up" all the dimensions of $\mathbb{C}^3$ in realising the trivial and standard representation as subrepresentations.

Let $e_1 = v_1 - v_2$ and $e_2 = v_2 - v_3$, then $V_2 \otimes V_2 = \big\langle e_1 \otimes e_1, e_1 \otimes e_2, e_2 \otimes e_1, e_2 \otimes e_2\big\rangle$. As you have stated, we have $V_2 \otimes V_2 \cong V_1 \oplus V_{-1} \oplus V_2$. However you are not going to be able to "express the previous irreps basis in terms of the basis of $V_2 \otimes V_2$". Why? Well before we realised the trivial and standard representations as subrepresentations of $\mathbb{C}^3$, but now we want a realisations as subrepresentations of $V_2 \otimes V_2$ which is a completely different vector space to $\mathbb{C}^3.$

What you want to do instead (and perhaps this is what you meant) is find a realisation of each irreducible representation as a subrepresentation of $V_2 \otimes V_2$. One way to do this is to use the projection homomorphism:

Let $V$ be a representation of $G$, and $W$ be an irreducible subrepresentation, then $$ \pi = \frac{\dim W}{|G|} \sum_{g \in G} \chi_{_{W}}(g) \cdot g $$ is a $G$-module projection from $V$ into the sum of all copies of $W$ appearing in $V$. You can find this in Fulton and Harris, equation $2.32$.

Note that we don't actually need the "$G$-module homomorphism-ness" of the projection, since we just want to use it to find a basis, so let's forget the scalars out front in $\pi$ and just apply $ \pi' = \sum_{g \in G} \chi_{_{W}}(g) \cdot g $ instead.

Let's find a basis for the trivial representation inside $V_2 \otimes V_2$. We know that $\chi_{_{V_1}}(g) = 1$ for all $g \in S_3$. Thus our projection formula into the trivial subrepresentation is

$$ \sum_{g \in S_3} g$$

Since we know that the trivial representation is $1$ dimensional ,we just have to find a single non-zero element fixed by $S_3$. So let's apply our projection to $e_1 \otimes e_1 = (v_1-v_2) \otimes (v_1 - v_2)$ and see what happens:

$$ \left(\sum_{g \in S_3} g \right)\cdot \big(e_1 \otimes e_1\big) $$
$$= e_1 \otimes e_1 + (123) \cdot (e_1 \otimes e_1) + (132) \cdot (e_1 \otimes e_1) + (12) \cdot (e_1 \otimes e_1) + (23) \cdot (e_1 \otimes e_1) + (13) \cdot (e_1 \otimes e_1)$$
$$ = \dots $$
$$ = 4e_1 \otimes e_1 + 4e_2 \otimes e_2 + 2e_1 \otimes e_2 + 2e_2 \otimes e_1$$.

You can check this this vector really is invariant under all $g \in S_3$. Therefore, as a subrepresentation of $V_2 \otimes V_2$, the trivial representation is
$$ \big\langle 2e_1 \otimes e_1 + 2e_2 \otimes e_2 + e_1 \otimes e_2 + e_2 \otimes e_1 \big\rangle$$.

You can do a similiar thing to find bases of the other two representations